# distinctUntilChanged() does not get executed on page load

Tags: angular, user-interface, rxjs, observable

When a page is loaded I run the following method and use the returned list in dropdown.

The tap and the switchMap block gets executed but not what's in distinctUntilChanged on page load.

After the page load, distinctUntilChanged gets executed correctly if I change the value of "formControl"

Why isn't distinctUntilChanged() executing on page load?

```js
        const sourceA$ = formControl.valueChanges.pipe(startWith('user-input-value'));
        return combineLatest(([sourceA$, sourceB$, sourceC$])).pipe(
                tap(([a, b, c]) => {
                  console.log(a); // gets executed on page load
                }),
                distinctUntilChanged(([a, b, c], [a2, b2, c2]) => {
                  return a === a2; // does not get executed on page load
                }),
                switchMap(([a, b, c]) => {
                  console.log(a); // gets executed on page load
                  return of([]);
                })
            );
```

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, can you please specify the reason behind it?

Comment: What happens when you console a and a2?

Comment: @MikeOne doesn't print anything in console on page load. But it does on subsequent executions

Comment: @MikeOne Could it be because it doesn't have a previous value on page load? If so, how can we force it to execute on page load too?

Comment: Mmm… I mean.. it should still trigger I would expect? If you simply put a console.log in there as well (before the return obviously) like console.log(‘here’: a, a2) what does it print?

Comment: @MikeOne it prints nothing on page load but on subsequent executions, it prints previous and current values. Basically, the code execution doesn't even go inside distinctUntilChanged block on page load

Comment: This seems fairly much impossible as these are piped functions..Sounds more like a debug problem to me?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the implementation of the `distinctUntilChanged` operator in RxJS@7.x, it checks if it's the first value, then it always emits it without calling the provided/predefined `comparator` function.

From the `distinctUntilChanged` [implementation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/distinctUntilChanged.ts#L165):

> If it's the first value, we always emit it.
> Otherwise, we compare this key to the previous key, and if the comparer returns false, we emit.

```js
if (first || !comparator!(previousKey, currentKey)) { // ... }
```

So, in your case, the `comparator` function you provided won't be called at the first time until the next value comes.

Answer (score 1):

`distinctUntilChanged` expect 2 values: the current and the previous. It compare both and run only if the latter is different from the previous.

In your case you not have a previous value, because on page load you cannot have any previous value, so your operator never works.

For more info: [distinctUntilChange](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/distinctuntilchanged)